# class github-button breaks addEventListener

Tags: javascript, github

I found something funny trying to add Mixpanel analytics on Github buttons: class="github-button" breaks any addEventListener for reasons I don't understand.

Here's a sample of code:

```
<head>
    <script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
            <!-- Header -->
            <span class='text'>
                <a id="star" class="github-button" href="https://github.com/tnguyen42/FAQ.sh" data-icon="octicon-star" data-style="mega" data-count-href="/tnguyen42/FAQ.sh/stargazers" data-count-api="/repos/tnguyen42/FAQ.sh#stargazers_count" data-count-aria-label="# stargazers on GitHub" aria-label="Star tnguyen42/FAQ.sh on GitHub">Star</a>

                <a id="fork" class="github-button" href="https://github.com/tnguyen42/FAQ.sh/fork" data-icon="octicon-repo-forked" data-style="mega" data-count-href="/tnguyen42/FAQ.sh/network" data-count-api="/repos/tnguyen42/FAQ.sh#forks_count" data-count-aria-label="# forks on GitHub" aria-label="Fork tnguyen42/FAQ.sh on GitHub">Fork</a>
            </span>

            <span class='logoContainer'>
                <a class='logo'>FAQ</a>
            </span>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var star = document.getElementById("star");
                var fork = document.getElementById("fork");

                function starClick() {
                    mixpanel.track('Star Click');
                    console.log("Star Click");
                }

                function forkClick() {
                    mixpanel.track('Fork Click');
                    console.log("Fork Click");
                }

                star.addEventListener("click", starClick, false);
                fork.addEventListener("click", forkClick, false);
            </script>
        </div>
</body>
```

Now, this code won't work. `star` is recognized, `fork` is recognized, but coming to `addEventListener`, I will never get any console log that are supposed to be executed.

Now, if I simply remove the `class="github-button"`, everything will work just fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/stz73kvv/ (I removed `mixpanel.track` as it is not defined). The issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Also, a word of advice: If you post code in a public forum, or really just write code for anyone other than yourself, avoid using terms like *BITCH* or *BITCHY*.

Comment: What if you add <head><script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script></head>?

I forgot to add it

Comment: Haha, yeah, sorry about that ^^
I use a lot of language in my console.log() ^^